# Merging tow dataframes in R that do not have common columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, data-cleaning

I have been trying to merge two dataframes in r that do not have the same column. The output I get is one that has an extra set of rows and duplicated values. My attempt is below and edits to the code a welcome.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c("A","B", "C", "D", "E"),
                  B=c(7, 9, 8, 3, 2),
                  C=c(3, 5, 2, 9, 9))

df2 <- data.frame(D=c(1, 3, 3, 4, 5),
                  E=c(7, 7, 8, 3, 2))

df3<-merge(x=df1, y=df2, by=NULL)
```

This works but now the output gives me 25 observations of 5 variables. Where the is an extra set of rows like a duplication. ( disclaimer this is not the entire dataset here just a subset of it) .

```
     A     B     C     D     E  
1 A      7      3     1     7 
2 B      9      5     1     7 
3 C      8      2     1     7
4 D      3      9     1     7 
5 E      2      9     1     7 
6 A      7      3     3     7 
7 B      9      5     3     7 
8 C      8      2     3     7
```

My desired output is something like the one below (5 observations and 5 variables), where I do not an additional set of rows and duplicated values.

```
 A     B     C     D     E  
1 A      7      3     1     7 
2 B      9      5     3     7 
3 C      8      2     3     8
4 D      3      9     4     3 
5 E      2      9     5     2
```

Comment: use `cbind`: `cbind(df1, df2)`

Comment: Try `cbind(df1, df2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments already mentioned you can use cbind() to accomplish that.

```
df3 <- cbind(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As *the `cbind` data frame method is just a wrapper for `data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)`* you can also use:

```
df3 <- data.frame(df1, df2, check.names = FALSE)
#df3 <- data.frame(df1, df2) #Alternative

df3
#  A B C D E
#1 A 7 3 1 7
#2 B 9 5 3 7
#3 C 8 2 3 8
#4 D 3 9 4 3
#5 E 2 9 5 2
```